# Массив затронутых строк во время выполнения UPDATE запроса в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Можно ли получить массив затронутых строк во время выполнения UPDATE запроса в MySQL?

Comment: Сделайте эту выборку ДО обновления. Т.е. со всеми теми же условиями отбора - но SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить список затронутых строк нельзя. Но если в таблицу добавить поле updated_at и обновлять его при обновлении, то потом можно сделать выборку обновленных данных обычным селектом.

Обращаю внимание на разницу между понятиями "отобран для обновления" и "затронут обновлением". Разницу отлично проиллюстрировал [@Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) в комментариях ниже.

Comment: Не совсем так. Можно сделать выборку только **фактически** обновлённых записей. См. напр. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8771a6d933e821a59ff256248ff6f2c

Comment: ну так я и написал, что если добавить поле времени обновления, то можно выбрать, а без него нет

Comment: См. внимательно fiddle. Обновление и фактическое обновление - это две большие разницы, далеко не все обновляемые записи обновляются фактически.

Comment: Вопрос про затронутые строки ведь и в вашем примере выберуться именно затронутые. Никакого противоречия не вижу

Comment: Я к тому, что нам неизвестно, что автор вкладывает в понятие "затронутые". И полагаю разумным, если Вы добавите соотв. пояснение для автора в свой ответ. Ведь если он под затронутыми подразумевает "отобранные для обновления" - то он не получит желаемого.

Comment: под "затронутыми" строками автор понимает те строки, количество которых подсчитывает mysqli_affected_rows()